# How to convert string to list?

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list:

```py
sample = ["['P001']"]
```

How to convert it into:

```py
sample = [["P001" ]]
```

I tried `[[x] for x in sample]` but the output is `[["[P001]"]]`

Edited : I am very sorry for the inconvenience because I have made mistake in the question I ask. Actually is the  `"P001"` a string. Sorry again.

Comment: Is `P001` defined as a variable, if not do you actually want this: `[["P001"]]` instead?

Comment: first you can convert into to string then again convet to list

Comment: P001 can only remain as a list since it can't be anything else

Answer (score 0):

If you want the output as this `[['P001']]`, you can do this:

```
>>> sample = ["[P001]"]
>>> [[sample[0].strip('[\]')]]
[['P001']]
```

But if you want the output as `[[P001]]` I don't know if that's possible. `P001` is not a python type, and if `P001` is a defined variable before then the modified list will hold the value of `P001` not the name itself. For example:

```
>>> P001 = 'something'
>>> sample = ["[P001]"]
>>> [eval(sample[0])]
[['something']]
```

Comment: But actually he want this output: sample = [[P001]]

Comment: That is invalid, `P001` is not a python keyword. And if `P001` is defined variable then the output would not be ` [[P001]]` it will be `[[value_of_P001]]`. I will update the answer with example.

Comment: Sorry that I make mistake when asking the question. The question has been edited.

Comment: Your second solution works in this task. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry that this is my first time asking question. I still can't upvote.

Comment: Don't wory, not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is an array of strings and each string consists of pattern like "[P001]". You need to loop over the outer array and run a match with each element to get the inner value, in this case 'P001'. Then you can append the value as you like.

```
s = ["[P001]", "[S002]"]
result = []
import re
for i in s:
    r = re.match(r"\[(.*?)\]", i)
    if r:
        result.append([r.group(1)])

print(result)
[['P001'], ['S002']]
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done just using a regular expression for alphanumeric characters:

```
sample = ["[P001,P002]","[P003,P004]"]

import re
sample = [re.findall("\w+", sublist) for sublist in sample]
```